# Avoiding duplication of function prototypes using constants in VBA for Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to eliminate code duplication in defining function prototypes in VBA, and this method doesn't quite seem to work.  Basically for most platforms except for 32-bit windows, we have the same exact prototypes, but only the DLL/dylib name changes.  So I am trying to find a way to get VBA to do what I want, but it keeps complaining about the library name not being a string constant (unless I hard code it).  Is there any way to get VBA to understand what I am trying to do?

Other things I tried: a compiler constant `#Const libName = "CoolProp_xls_x64.dll"` instead of `const libName ...` in each block, but then it said that libName was multiply defined (except that it isn't if it listens to the preprocessor flags

```
#If Win64 Then
    Const libName As String = "CoolProp_xls_x64.dll"
#ElseIf Win32 Then
    Const libName As String = ""
#ElseIf Mac Then
    #If MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >= 15 Then
        #If VBA7 Then ' 64-bit Excel 2016 for Mac
            Const libName As String = "libCoolProp.dylib"
        #Else ' 32-bit Excel 2016 for Mac
            Const libName As String = "libCoolProp_32bit.dll"
        #End If
    #Else ' 32-bit Excel 2011 for Mac
        Const libName As String = "libCoolProp_32bit.dll"
    #End If
#End If

#Const theLibName = libName

#If Mac Or Win64 Then
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib theLibName Alias "get_global_param_string" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_fluid_param_string_private Lib theLibName Alias "get_fluid_param_string" (ByVal fluid As String, ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PropsSI_private Lib theLibName Alias "PropsSI" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Name1 As String, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Name2 As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Ref As String) As Double
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PhaseSI_private Lib theLibName Alias "PhaseSI" (ByVal Name1 As String, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Name2 As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Ref As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Props1SI_private Lib theLibName Alias "Props1SI" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Ref As String) As Double
Private Declare PtrSafe Function HAPropsSI_private Lib theLibName Alias "HAPropsSI" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Input1Name As String, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Input2Name As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Input3name As String, ByVal Value3 As Double) As Double
'DEPRECATED
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Props_private Lib theLibName Alias "PropsS" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Name1 As Long, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Name2 As Long, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Ref As String) As Double
#Else 'Win32
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_stdcall.dll" Alias "_get_global_param_string@12" (ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_fluid_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_stdcall.dll" Alias "_get_fluid_param_string@16" (ByVal param As String, ByVal param As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PropsSI_private Lib "CoolProp_stdcall.dll" Alias "_PropsSI@32" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Name1 As String, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Name2 As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Ref As String) As Double
Private Declare PtrSafe Function PhaseSI_private Lib "CoolProp_stdcall.dll" Alias "_PhaseSI@36" (ByVal Name1 As String, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Name2 As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Ref As String, ByVal Output As String, ByVal n As Integer) As Long
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Props1SI_private Lib "CoolProp_stdcall.dll" Alias "_Props1SI@8" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Ref As String) As Double
Private Declare PtrSafe Function HAPropsSI_private Lib "CoolProp_stdcall.dll" Alias "_HAPropsSI@40" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Input1Name As String, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Input2Name As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Input3name As String, ByVal Value3 As Double) As Double
'DEPRECATED
Private Declare PtrSafe Function Props_private Lib "CoolProp_stdcall.dll" Alias "_PropsS@32" (ByVal Output As String, ByVal Name1 As String, ByVal Value1 As Double, ByVal Name2 As String, ByVal Value2 As Double, ByVal Ref As String) As Double
#End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. VBA doesn't have a preprocessor in the traditional sense, despite appearances. `#Const` declarations can be used only in `#If` statements and cannot be substituted into actual code, while the `Lib` in a `Declare` statement must be a literal (not merely a constant, a *literal*). Furthermore, as you've noticed, `#Const` declarations aren't subject to conditional compilation themselves, so you can't even group conditions to make things easier. Isn't scripting fun?

As far as I can tell you need four blocks. Write conditions to the blocks rather than the other way around:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_xls_x64.dll" ...
#ElseIf MAC_OFFICE_VERSION >= 15 And VBA7 Then  
    '64-bit Excel 2016 for Mac
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "libCoolProp.dylib" Alias "get_global_param_string" ...
#ElseIf Mac Then
    '32-Bit Excel for Mac
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "libCoolProp_32bit.dll" Alias "get_global_param_string" ...
#ElseIf Win32 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function get_global_param_string_private Lib "CoolProp_stdcall.dll" Alias "_get_global_param_string@12" ...
#EndIf
```